# "Нехарактерное место" или "не характерное место"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно написать: "нехарактерное место" или "не характерное место"?

Answer (score 1):

Обе формы возможны, надо смотреть по тексту.

Разницы по смыслу практически нет, но встречаются **обязательные отрицательные конструкции**, например:

отнюдь не характерное место (усиление отрицания);

не характерное ли это место... (риторический вопрос);

стая рыб может оказаться в **не характерном** для обычной стоянки, а совершенно **случайном** месте (противопоставление).

Но: совершенно нехарактерный - **усиление утверждения, слитное написание**

Comment: Sibylla, "характерный" и "обычный" - в научном языке это синонимы. Да и в быту такое противопоставление вряд ли возможно.

Comment: Да, попробую исправить.

Answer (score 1):

Фразу целиком приведите, пожалуйста.

Скорее всего, раз такой вопрос появился, ваш случай требует слитного написания, когда написание раздельное, оно обычно не вызывает сомнений. Но можно и ошибиться, не зная фразы.

Если это что-то типа ***"Не характерное место, а характерное время"***, то написание, естественно, раздельное.